# Cannot Add Apple ID to Xcode: Your session has expired. Please log in

Tags: xcode, apple-id

I'm on OS X 10.11.6 with Xcode 7.3.1.

When I attempt to add my Apple ID to Xcode (Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts), it gives me the error message:

> **Your session has expired. Please log in.**
>
> Try signing in again or contact Apple Developer Support to resolve account access issues.

My Apple ID account works fine for all other Apple services. I can access iCloud, the Mac App Store, the iTunes store, `appleid.apple.com`, `developer.apple.com`, etc... the only thing that's having issues with my account is Xcode.

I don't have any paid account right now. In the past (~6 years ago), I did have a paying iOS Developer account, but I let that expire after a single year.

I'm planning on calling Apple Developer Support tomorrow afternoon to see if they can help (I suspect my account might be messed up on their end), but just incase... does anyone have any suggestions for what might be the problem and how to fix this?

(I have restarted my computer and Xcode already. I've also given it several hours between tries for Apple to wrangle any server side issues. And my network connection is fine.)

Comment: I have same problem , Could you resolve it .

Comment: Jesus, Apple. This is ridiculous.

Comment: I have same problem even when i update xcode 8.0 to 8.2  :(

Comment: I'm guessing Apple had some kind of network outage, because this went from getting 2 upvotes in 4 months to 11 upvotes in 6 hours. I'll let you all know - when I called Apple Developer Support, they told me that my account looked fine on their end. They had me clear Safari's cache, telling me that Xcode and Safari share their web cache. That didn't end up fixing my problem (I just gave up - it still doesn't work for me) - but maybe it'll fix the problem for someone else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happened to me too, just today also.  Turning on 2-factor authentication on my Apple ID solved it.  Lame that we had to search around the net for answers though.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if, four months later, it turns out that was my problem all along. My iMac is broken at the moment... not really sure how I can check if your answer is right or not. If people start saying this works for them, I guess I'll just mark it as accepted.

Comment: Marked as correct since other people are saying it worked for them. It's probably unrelated to my actual issue, but given I'm in no position to test this right now, I'll just accept your answer.

Comment: This solves the problem, but with fastlane double-factor validation does not work, activating this option, logging into xcode and deactivating it, works perfectly

Comment: Upvote, turning 2FA on, signing into Xcode, and then disabling 2FA worked.  It's still incredibly annoying, as turning on 2FA takes time, and then disabling it forces you to choose new security questions, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem and it seems to have been related to needing to authenticate my iCloud account in system preferences. At some point my mac was giving me 2fa codes that Apple wasn't accepting. Using the code given to me on my phone worked so now all is well again.